# Is there any way to identify the unused Column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I need to identify the table and particular columns which are not used and not updating by the app. based on the analysis we need to migrate db.

we tried to run queries but not getting the result that I'm expecting.

Comment: "*we tried to run queries*" - which queries?! "*not getting the result that I'm expecting.*" - which result were you expecting, and which result did you get?

Comment: There is no way you can get that information out of the database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.